# How to Replace in RegEx Notepad++

Tags: find, find-and-replace

I cant seem find any answers on this but how does one find and replace in notepad++.

For example: I am trying to find all lines that contain 4 pipes between the amount and name. How can I find this to add an additional pipe, making it 5  pipes between?

```
$13.00||||Andover Lakes||||1512
$45.00|||||Hillside Bay||||1513
$45.00||||Crystal Manor||||1514
$89.00|||||Cypress Resort||||1515
```

I tried `\|\|\|\|[a-z]` but then it changes the first initial to `[a-z]`. What is the pattern I need in order to find something without having to literally change what I don't want to change?

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\d)\|{4}(?=[a-zA-Z])`
- Replace with: `|$0`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\d)         # positive lookbehind, zero length assertion that makes sure we have a digit before
\|{4}           # 4 pipes
(?=[a-zA-Z])    # positive lookahead, zero length assertion that makes sure we have a letter after
```

**Replacement:**

```
|           # a pipe
$0          # the whole match (i.e. 4 pipes)
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]